# Adobe photoshop CC 2017- How to Fix paste special option is not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cc-2017

I'm trying to copy rectangle and paste it by using **Paste Special > Paste in Place** command. But, it's not working.
[image]

How can I Fix it?

Comment: Hi. I can't reproduce this problem with the latest 2023 version (24.7).  It seems to work just fine [see example here](https://imgur.com/dkCThkL)  Perhaps consider upgrading.

Comment: @BillyKerr I've solved my problem with the help of Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V Commands simply.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the selected layer, selected object and what is in your clipboard.

If the layer is locked, paste options will be grayed out.
If you have text in the clipboard you can only paste this in text boxes.

In your case you selected a vector layer that you can't paste into.

Answer (score -2):

The Paste Special command will Paste whatever is in your clipboard (has been copied) into a selection.

Create a selection first and then the Paste Special options will be available.

Comment: After creating the selection first. The result is same.